# Setup CloudTrail for SQS events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudtrail

I was following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html doc to pass SQS management events to CloudTrail. I did not get any particular step to set it up specifically for SQS. After following the steps I was able to get other events in AWS services to start showing up but none for SQS, is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudTrail is for all services, you cannot restrict it just for SQS.

As for SQS events not showing up, there is a lag in the events to show up in CloudTrail console. Are you sure there was a SQS event? How long did you wait?

From: [CloudTrail FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/#event-payload-timeliness-and-delivery-frequency)

> Q: How long does it take CloudTrail to deliver an event for an API
>   call?  Typically, CloudTrail delivers an event within 15 minutes of
>   the API call.

Comment: I waited for around 10-15 minutes

Comment: It is not available in Event Stream, but you have to actually open the S3 log files to analyze it.

Comment: Why don't you use the CloudTrail console? I see at least 6 types of SQS evemts in CloudTrail.

Comment: CLoudTrail only supports Queue level SQS APIs (CreateQueue, DeleteQueue, etc) and **does not** support Message level SQS APIs (PutMessage, DeleteMessage). In some regions, CloudTrail may take up to 25 minutes to deliver Queue level APIs. You can use the Console or S3 to look at your events. There is no special configuration for SQS.